# Image doesn't exist error

Tags: react-native

I took a reference of`ScrollView` from React Native official tutorial.

The image code just like
`<Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />`

When i try to build it shows that

The development server returned response error code: 500
URL: http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false
Body:

```
{"from":"F:\\ReactNativeProject\\FirstProject\\index.android.js","to":"./img/favicon.png","message":"Unable to resolve module `./img/favicon.png` from `F:\\ReactNativeProject\\FirstProject\\index.android.js`: Directory F:\\ReactNativeProject\\FirstProject\\img\\favicon.png doesn't exist","name":"UnableToResolveError","type":"UnableToResolveError","errors":[{}]}
```

I set the image to my folder that is `F:\ReactNativeProject\FirstProject\img`

and the image name is `favicon`

Why it shows the error ?  Some one can tell me why? Thanks in advace.

New error is `F:/ReactNativeProject/FirstProject/index.android.js: Unexpected token (9:25)
  at F:\ReactNativeProject\FirstProject\index.android.js:9:25`

My code is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import{ AppRegistry, ScrollView, Image, Text, View } from 'react-native'

class IScrolledDownAndWhatHappenedNextShockedMe extends Component {
  render() {
      return(
        <ScrollView>
<Image source={../../img/favicon.png} />
</ScrollView>
    );
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('FirstProject', () => IScrolledDownAndWhatHappenedNextShockedMe);
```

Answer (score 2):

`require` is used to refer a module/file. Hence You are getting the error.

```
<Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
```

should be:

```
<Image source={path/favicon.png} />//path=path of image
```

Comment: thanks for your responding , but i don't get it . If my root is `F:\ReactNativeProject\FirstProject\img`  should i try like `<Image source={img/favicon.png} />` in my case ?   It fail in the end.

Comment: try <Image source={../../img/favicon.png} /> or <Image source={../../../img/favicon.png} />

Comment: thanks for help , i change with it but it show another error , i am the bignner with react-native , would you please help me again ? thanks.

Comment: what issues you are getting?

Comment: it should be <Image source={"../../img/favicon.png"} />

Comment: I changed to `<Image source={"../../img/favicon.png"} />` , there's no changing with the error.

Comment: wait the error just like...`Warning:Failed prop type : Invalid prop source supplied to image`

Comment: I am  not getting you. You need to debug.

Comment: This is incorrect. source accepts types of `ImageURISource | ImageURISource[] | ImageRequireSource`, not string. It should be `<Image source={require("./some/path/to.png")} />`

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue using this solution

```
                                        {data?.image ?
                                        <View>
                                            <Image
                                                source={{ uri: data?.image ? data?.image : "" }}
                                            />
                                        </View> : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check "react-native" imports include the Image class! I was having the same problem and the solution was a bad import of Image object.

See pic:

[Image import in App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfacW.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).